# type constraints in Generic types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have below code

```
interface BaseModalProps {
  name:string
}
interface AddToListModalProps extends BaseModalProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
export const AddToListModal: FC<AddToListModalProps> = ({
  name,
  age,
}: AddToListModalProps) => <h1>{`${name} ${age.toString()}`}</h1>;


// bad TS syntax, what is the correct syntax? 
export const dynamicModal: FC<{T extends BaseModalProps}> = AddToListModal;
```

where I want to assign `dynamicModal` to a Component that has props extended from `BaseModalProps`. the `AddToListModal` is a good example. If you assign a non-complying component to `dynamicModal` I want a type error

I've tried a couple of solution and non of them works,,, any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make generic type:

```ts
export type DynamicModal<T extends BaseModalProps> = FC<T>;

// Works fine
export const AddToListModal: DynamicModal<AddToListModalProps> = ({
  name,
  age,
}) => <h1>{`${name} ${age.toString()}`}</h1>;

// Errors as expected
export const EpicFail: DynamicModal<{ a: number }> = ({ a }) => <p>{a.toString()}</p>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=87&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoYAOxiSk3STgCEUBnJAWQgBMUAbAAo4wbOAG9ycOFRQgkALjYwo1AOYUAvhUo06DNEwCCPHgBUIAGWDLufISLFIAHrSo8xrDnYHCIoiSkZOUU4ZVUqDSCUNVCqAFcQACM6LR0XSFg4GABPMCYAERzZEGA0H34AHjM4FzcPFnYuXl9HAD44AF5EYhgAOgAxAGFqtooM6Hg0CCplOBNzKxsYCoU4IpKyisqFi2tbFod-Ng7ugApJaRKkABpo2LvNAEoujsqACwBGNvEAAwAScTXTRwQExJB9GAQADKKnUZyeml+mkqAHovmNyOQJllprN4ABRMBlAYoYD8NYbORbQ6VcRwFBrBLJOhwTSnOAXBlsl6dN5gH4oSEwuGRBEo1ECihAA)